# Draggable Input Price from Market Price

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am trying to create a horizontal line that the user can drag, and the price should be saved as a variable.

```
StopPrice = input.price(title="Stop Price", defval=1.08, confirm = true)
```

So here, Im starting at a default value of 1.08,

But I want the line to start at the market price or 15 pips

Ive tried setting

```
StopPrice = input.price(title="Stop Price", defval=close, confirm = true)
```

that is not working either.

What can I try?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. `input.price()` expects a `const float`. You cannot use it with dynamic values.

Comment: Is there any other approach that I could use to do this. I basically need to input the price from the chart. By tapping on it etc

Comment: No, there is no another way.